# How can I make sure my next image wont come up

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I make sure that my next image will not come up until my first one has been completely hidden? It is written in Javascript and is a single line code, I wanted to make sure that the next one would not fade in before the last one fades out...since that causes the slider to distort. Here is the code:

```
   $('.carousel_slider a:first-child').fadeOut().hide().next().fadeIn().show().end().appendTo('.carousel_slider');
```

How can I make sure that my next image will not come up until my first one has been completely hidden?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example http://jsfiddle.net/pV57K/.

```
var $first = $('.carousel_slider a:first-child');
$first.fadeOut(function() {
    $first.hide();
     var $next = $first.next();
     $next.fadeIn(function() {
        $next.show();
        $first.appendTo('.carousel_slider');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/), provide a callback to `fadeOut()`:

```
.fadeOut( [duration ] [, complete ] )
```

> If supplied, the callback is fired once the animation is complete. **This can be useful for stringing different animations together in sequence.** The callback is not sent any arguments, but this is set to the DOM element being animated.

Instead of writing `$('thing').fadeOut().next().fadeIn()` you should write:

```js
$('thing').fadeOut(function() {
    $(this).next().fadeIn()
})
```

This will ensure that the call to `.fadeIn()` does not happen until the call to `.fadeOut()` has completed. Also, `.fadeOut()` will set `display: none` once the opacity reaches 0, and `.fadeIn()` will restore `display`. This means that you don't actually need your calls to `.hide()` and `.show()`.